# Maven failing to aquire dependencies

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

so I'm still very new to Maven so I really don't understand how the whole process works very well. Anyway I'm trying to get maven to compile my project, when I run the command "mvn compile" first it gives me a build failure if however I run the command "mvn package" it will succeed and anyway subsequent "mvn compile"s will work after that. My issue is I need to submit it to git which sends it off for review to jenkins, it's at that time that it is failing and I don't know how to fix it. Here is the log

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox
Checkout:my_dropbox / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@427e3f2
Using strategy: Gerrit Trigger
Last Built Revision: Revision 05182398b298d442d1c238673a40beb52b83386f (anything_but_blank)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://jenkins@gerrit:29418/my_dropbox.git
Commencing build of Revision 0980748fbbd29ff9acd2134dd55cb84afb577dd7 (anything_but_blank)
Checking out Revision 0980748fbbd29ff9acd2134dd55cb84afb577dd7 (anything_but_blank)
Parsing POMs
[my_dropbox] $ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/Maven/Maven_3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/Maven/Maven_3 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.19.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar 40598
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/pom.xml clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for SimpleDropbox:SimpleDropbox:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 35, column 9
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
Projects to build: [MavenProject: SimpleDropbox:SimpleDropbox:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/pom.xml]
projectStarted SimpleDropbox:SimpleDropbox:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Fiachra 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1(default-clean)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ SimpleDropbox ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/target
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1(default-clean)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-resources)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ SimpleDropbox ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/src/main/resources
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-resources)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1(default-compile)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SimpleDropbox ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
mojoFailed org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1(default-compile)[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[3,23] error: package org.junit does not exist

[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[7,16] error: package org.junit does not exist

[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[11,2] error: cannot find symbol

[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

projectFailed SimpleDropbox:SimpleDropbox:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
sessionEnded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.054s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 20 09:03:25 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Projects to build: [MavenProject: SimpleDropbox:SimpleDropbox:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/pom.xml]
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_dropbox/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my_dropbox/modules/SimpleDropbox$SimpleDropbox/builds/2013-02-20_09-03-14/archive/SimpleDropbox/SimpleDropbox/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SimpleDropbox-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project SimpleDropbox: Compilation failure
cause : Compilation failure
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project SimpleDropbox: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
channel stopped
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

and here is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SimpleDropbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>SimpleDropbox</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Fiachra</name>
  <description>It's a simple dropbox</description>

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.7</source>
               <target>1.7</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>

        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
       <archive>
         <manifest>
           <mainClass>main.java.Main</mainClass>
           <packageName>main.java</packageName>
         </manifest>
         <manifestEntries>
           <mode>development</mode>
         </manifestEntries>
       </archive>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the local clean install.

```
fiachra@fiachra-Precision-WorkStation-T5500 my_dropbox (develop *%=) $ mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Fiachra
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 20 10:28:00 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/361M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
fiachra@fiachra-Precision-WorkStation-T5500 my_dropbox (develop *%=) $ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Fiachra
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[3,23] error: package org.junit does not exist

[ERROR] /home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[9,2] error: cannot find symbol

[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[3,23] error: package org.junit does not exist

/home/fiachra/work/my_dropbox/src/test/java/TestSomething.java:[9,2] error: cannot find symbol


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 20 10:28:06 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/361M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : Got it.

In your POM, you modifiy the default sourceDirectory (you should not un less you have a good reason)

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

Therefor, maven tries to compile the Test classes during the compile phase. JUNIT is not available (scope of JUNIT dependency is test).

Remove

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

And this should work

Comment: I made sure to commit the pom, I even checked on git just to be safe. The first time my IDE did include the JUNIT but I removed that which gave me errors on my unit tests which were fixed after I added the JUNIT dependency to the the pom and updated the maven project. The jar is even included under "Maven Dependencies" now. Locally the first time I do "mvn compile" it fails, once I do "mvn package" it succeeds and any subsequent compile or tests will work after that, but only after I do mvn package. I don't think it's a timeout since it fails after one second and I have ran it a few times.

Comment: I should also point out that I am getting the same error msg locally if I do "mvn clean" "mvn compile"

Comment: So that last comment explains much, because, if I'm not mistaken, Jenkins by default performs mvn clean install command. So at least you have a reliable and consistent way to test it. Could you do mvn clean install on your local machine an post the output?

Comment: You're welcome. Generally speaking, I would recommend you try to keep your pom as thin as possible, to rely the more possible on convention rather than configuration.

Comment: Yeah, my pom is probably a bit messy there was some issue I was having with the main class not being specified and the wrong version of java being used. It took me ages to find the right solution after copying and pasting many lines, I guess I forgot to remove one.